# How do I use Google Talk with only one Google account?

Tags: google-talk

I have two Google accounts set up on my Verizon Motorola DROID RAZR MAXX.

I wish to use Google Talk with only one of the two accounts, but not the other. But I still want to use Google Talk with the second account when I use it from the desktop and in other places.

Is there a way to have Google Talk sign in to only one of my two Google accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You chose which account(s) to sign in with and what status they have individually. Just ensure you've signed out of any account you don't want to use.

---

> And how exactly do I do that? There doesn't seem to be any option in Google Talk's settings to sign out of an account

1. Open Google Talk
2. Select your current account, to show a list of all accounts
3. Chose the account you want to sign out of
4. Select your own account
5. Change from Available to Sign Out

Comment: Aha, I finally found the Sign Out option, in the menu after selecting the account in question.